# Finder suddenly very slow

Tags: macos, finder, performance, sonoma

Suddenly all the Finder actions become very slow, while using other apps like Chrome is very fast. When moving files to different folders, I always get a "preparing to move to" pop-up, selecting a file, right-clicking a file, moving a file to trash even just one file 500KB file needs like 30 seconds to execute.

Even just selecting Finder causes a few second delay. The problem still persist even if no other apps are open. I'm on an M1 Mac running Sonoma 14.0, using 420 GB out of 494GB. When I check the memory usage with Activity Monitor it's consistently around 6.3 GB out of 16 GB even when Finder is lagging.

Checking with activity monitor, both ApplicationsStorageExtension (3113) and Finder (703) can spike to above 50% cpu (ApplicationsStorageExtension (3113) usually spiking higher and more often). WindowServer (402) can also get above 20 % cpu. (not simultaneously).

I was recently messing with some permissions so that could be the issue, to be specific I modified the permissions of the Users folder and all enclosed items (Is this bad?) Any ideas on what I could try to fix this, short of reinstalling macOS(reinstalling macOS didn't work either)?

I have tried relaunching finder (from the force quit menu), restarting computer, and reinstalling the os from recovery mode. Also, finder seems to especially struggle and stagger for like 10 seconds when I click Go (on the top toolbar).

Comment: 420 of 494 Gb on the disk? That's quite full. The OS (the bit that you reinstall) cannot be altered, so there's no point in doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After talking to AppleCare support they suspect it has to do with the new Sonoma OS and system can be slow for a day or so while indexing happens.

After Apple support, I figured out this had something to do with iCloud and just turning off icloud  fixed my slowness.

For anyone having the same issue, look at iCloud and remember to restart after disabling iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

Worth a try: Cmd-Alt-Esc/Finder or Apple menu→Force Quit…→Finder then Relaunch.

Comment: Sadly, I already tried this and restarting my computer.